# React Native Countdown Timer keeps resetting

Tags: react-native, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer set at every 20 seconds an alert prompt is shown and a choice to extend timer or cancel. 
Every time i would go to another screen on my app and come back to the home page, the timer keeps resetting itself and will have multiple timers in the background and then multiple prompts. This even includes when extending timer as well.

How can i stop it from resetting the timer each time i go through another screen on the app and keep it to one timer?

Please see my example code:

```
import CountDown from 'react-native-countdown-component';

export default class App extends React.Component {



constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      timer: 20,
    };
  }
};
timesUp = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "ALERT ",
      'Would you like to extend timer?',
      [
        {
          text: 'Extend Timer',
          onPress: () =>
            this.setState(previousState => ({
              timerId: ++previousState.timerId,
            })),
        },

        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  };

render(){
 return(
        <View style={styles.countdownContainer}>
          <CountDown
            id={this.state.timerId}
            until={this.state.timer}
            onFinish={this.timesUp}
            timeToShow={['M', 'S']}
            digitStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFF' }}
            size={20}
          />
        </View>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can i stop it from resetting the timer each time i go through
>   another screen

It is resetting because the component is **unmounted** when you change the screen.

You can define your timer in your *top level* component. Top level component is never unmounted, so your timer will not be canceled when you change screen.

Comment: i moved to the top level component but now the alert prompt won't show up to let me  be able to extend timer, any idea how i could fix that?

Comment: You can use `redux`, or `contex API` to pass the state between components. If your component tree is not too deep, simply pass the state down as prop, and show your alert on your desired screen based on the prop you passed from the top level component. @Joe